# Does grape provide a template to build services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

https://github.com/intridea/grape

Is there a way to automatically generate a template for an application which will use grape to provide REST like interfaces. I am looking for something like "rails new app" which will provide me the skeleton to build on. If not what should I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but there are several [example apps with different stacks and functionality](https://github.com/intridea/grape/wiki#apps) on their wiki.

You can mix and match from what you see there, or just clone one of them to get started.

Also, Grape's DSL itself will guide you towards REST. You declare resources and then use the http verbs to define the requests.

Answer (score -1):

[grape-starter](https://github.com/LeFnord/grape-starter) seems to be what you're looking for.

Install the gem (`gem install grape-starter`) and create your new API with `grape-starter new awesome_api`.

For more options, such as choosing an ORM, or setting the prefix, use `grape-starter -h`. I recommend to have a look on the README.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16344478)

Comment: install the gem (`gem install grape-starter`) and create your new API with `grape-starter new awesome_api`, for more options, such as choosing an ORM, or setting the prefix call it with `-h`, I recommend to have a look on the README